# Embedded CSS/HTML Not Rendering in Teams

Tags: html, microsoft-teams

I have created an HTML table, and when sent to outlook it renders as expected.

When sent to a Teams Channel address, it seems to ignore a number of the attributes.

Any ideas why this may be happening and how to get around it?

Did see 1 reference to Teams not liking CSS entries, so rewrote to embed all tags at every level of the table and still no joy.

All display as expected in Outlook!

Thanks

Originally Tried

HTML

Copy

```
`<body>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">

table{
border-collapse:collapse;
border:1px solid #000000;
}

table td{
border:1px solid #000000;
}
</style>

<table style="border:1px solid #000000; width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr style="border-top:1px solid #000000;">
        <th>"Table 1"</th>
    
</table>

<table style="border:1px solid black; width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr style="border-top:1px solid #000000;">
        <th>"Table 2"<th>

     
</table>
</body>`
```

And then reworked to

HTML

```
`<html>
    <body>
        <table cellspacing=0 style="border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #000000; font-family: Arial"> 
                       <th  style="width:0*;border:1px solid #000000;">
                       "Field Header 1"
                       </th>
                       <th  style="width:0*;border:1px solid #000000;">
                       "Field Header 2"
                       </th>
                       <th  style="width:0*;border:1px solid #000000;">
                       "Field Header 3"
                       </th>
                       <th  style="width:0*;border:1px solid #000000;">
                       "Field Header 4"
                       </th>
                       <th  style="width:0*;border:1px solid #000000;">
                       "Field Header 5"
                       </th>                       
                       <tr> 
                <td style="width:0*;border:1px solid #000000;">              
                "Field Value 1"
                     </td>           
                 <td style="width:0*; border:1px solid #000000; text-align: center">             
                 "Field Value 2"
                     </td>           
                 <td style="width:0*; border:1px solid #000000; text-align: center">              
                 "Field Value 3"                     
                                 </td>           
                 <td style="width:0*; border:1px solid #000000; text-align: center">              
                 "Field Value 4"                     
                                 </td>           
                 <td style="width:0*; border:1px solid #000000;background-color: #ff0000;color: #ffffff; text-align: center">
                                 "Field Value 5"                     
                                 </td>
                      </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>`
```

Whilst showing correctly, table borders are not showing on either. The colour is also not showing on the broken down version, yet the font set is.

Comment: How are you sending the HTML in Teams channel? Have you created any incoming webhook or bot or just manually sending the table?

Comment: Emailing it through internal SMTP to the channel as an embedded item.
Shows fine in outlook and displays in Teams, just missing some of the attributes.

Comment: We tried to repro this issue by converting the html table in browser and copying the content and sending via email to Team's channel. This is rendering as below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/len3n.png  Could you please confirm if you are trying the same or any different?

Comment: The output is generated from a report generator, and renders in Browser and when embedded via SMTP to Outlook.
When sending to Teams via the same method, not getting the same results.

Comment: These are the supported text format in MS Teams. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-text-formats